# Embedding a JFrame in an Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I have found an open source application that creates a [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) to display some content. I would like to "embed" this [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) into an applet, so everything that is displayed in the Jframe will be displayed in the applet - is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What problems are you having when you try it?

Comment: *"I have found.."*  The net is a big place - care to share an URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an instance of the frame.
2. Get the content pane of the frame.
3. Add the content pane to the applet.

Comment: Don't forget the menu bar! (Presuming the OP is actually referring to a `JApplet` as opposed to what they wrote in the post title).

Answer (score 2):

> ..open source application that creates a JFrame..

Since the source is available, take whatever they do in the frame, and do that instead in an applet (with some slight variants & gotchas).

Some typical problems with using the frame content in an applet are that:

1. The programmers might have set the GUI visible in the constructor, meaning you cannot get access to the content pane without showing a free floating GUI element on-screen.
2. Custom painting direct to the frame (eeek).  There's no getting that stuff.  But then, any programmer that incompetent should not be 'open'ing their source in the first place.
3. A frame programmer would typically use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as an exit behavior for the frame.  It is not permitted (or necessary) for a sand-boxed applet to end the VM.  Even a trusted applet would (and should) normally be prevented from calling `System.exit(int)`.
4. Frame based code often does things that either require trust in an applet, or alternate strategies to achieve the same goal.

Points 3 & 4 are less applicable/relevant if the frame was designed to be launched using web start.  And since I mention webstart..

Note that it is generally easier to 'convert' a frame to be launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) than it is either to create and deploy an applet, or to convert a frame to an applet.  Unless there is some functionality of an applet that is vital & not available to an application (which is unlikely, given you started with the application), I would recommend launching the app. via JWS, rather than doing a conversion.